# How to send a POST request to login with jquery to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

How would you post login to here? I am trying to make an API for a game known as ROBLOX, I'm trying to POST to the url https://www.roblox.com/newlogin Here is my current code:

```
payload = {'username': 'usernamehere', 'password': 'passwordhere'}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://www.roblox.com/newlogin',
        data: '',
        success: function (){
        alert("Success!");
    },
    dataType: '';
});
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using your `payload` object at all; you probably want `data` to equal `payload`. I'd recommend reading the official documentation on [**`.ajax()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: This is actually a remake of another working api for the same website, It was working and was written in python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value of username, password - which here it doesn't seem to be done. And then add that to your ajax function to send it to the link you need it to go to.

```
<script>
// jQuery Method
user = ("#username");
pass = ("#password");
// DOM Method
user = document.getElementById("username");
pass = document.getElementById("password");

// jQuery method
payload = {'username': user.val(), 'password': pass.val()}
// DOM method
payload = {'username': user.value, 'password': pass.value}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://www.roblox.com/newlogin',
    data: payload,
    success: function (){
    alert('Success!');
},
dataType: 'html';
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're mixing DOM and jQuery methods. `.val()` is jQuery.

Comment: Right, but so is the `$.ajax` method, from my understanding

Comment: What does that have to do with it? `pass.val()` needs to be `pass.value`. Or it should be `pass = $("#password")`.

Comment: Oh Okay... I get what you are saying now. Thank you for pointing it out.